# thermal vias on a A4988 step stick motor driver should they be soldered

Tags: pcb-assembly

What I want to know is should the thermal vias on the bottom side of the pcb have solder in them. They don't appear to have anything in them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need sufficient copper for heatsink up to 1A and forced air up to 2A

and sufficient number of VIA's to carry Amps

Comment: oh thanks so nothing to do with the via having nothing in them then. I was thinking it would affect the transfer of heat. Thanks. I've ordered myself a drv8825 instead. They can apparently provide more grunt.

Comment: yes good for 8.2 to 45V but more grunt with higher V motors. since they are limited to 2.5A continuous. and ?? surge. (with adequate heatsink)  otherwise auto  thermal shutdown

Comment: oh surge as in the gallop of current it takes when it switches on. Doh. Thanks anyway. since the chip is bigger I can fit a bigger heatsink on it without overlapping any passives which would be bad.

Comment: surge is always I=Vout/DCR. for DCR(ohms) of motor